# How to execute a script when new hardware is detected on Linux?

Tags: loops, automation, addition, hardware, detect

I want to execute my script when adding / removing of hardware is detected.

Now I use a loop and sleep every 10 sec, to recheck a new hardware, but I thought it would be better if I could put my script to system path that will run every time that hardware changes are detected, similar to "run every log in" when put script path to `/etc/rc.local`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Write a udev rule](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) that executes the script each time the appropriate hardware is added or removed.

> ### Running external programs upon certain events
>
> Yet another reason for writing udev rules is to run a particular program when a device is connected or disconnected. For example, you might want to execute a script to automatically download all of your photos from your digital camera when it is connected.

Comment: I'm sorry. I can't vote this reply because of my newbie status. However, I like it. thank you.

Comment: Once you give it a try and find that it works out you can accept it as the answer for this question. But do try it first.

Comment: SUBSYSTEM=="block", RUN+="/usr/bin/my-script"   #

Is that complete syntax to check all common storage--internal harddisk, usb hardisk, cd, dvd, and sd ?

Comment: It might catch a few you don't want. Restrict it to something with a "d" in the right place, or filter on the device node in the script.

Comment: I have read. I'm going to try again. I will be back to report. (What does it mean " Restrict it to something with a "d" in the right place, " (driver ?)  I'm a terrible at english skill.)

Comment: There are block devices that are not disks. Most of the ones that are disks have a "d" in the name (`/dev/sd*`, `/dev/scd*`, etc.).

Comment: SUBSYSTEM=="block", RUN+="/home/a/test-udev.sh" #<< Why I gave 2 time result of "date >> test.txt" in "/home/a/test-udev.sh" when I just insert 1 thumb drive, that have only 1 partition, and another 2 times results, when eject it ?

Comment: Because the drive has a partition.

Comment: Wonderful! completely at ----SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="s*[0-9]", RUN+="/home/a/test-udev.sh"----- (I need sr1, too.)
thank you.